# Cómo obtener el valor de una variable de sesión (y mostrar el nombre del usuario logueado)

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de poner en un input el nombre de usuario de quien se logea en la página, pero no sé si se puede usar las mismas variables de un archivo PHP a otro distinto. Para el log in uso lo siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('scripts/connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
    else
    {
        $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
else
{
}

?>,
```

Pero en donde quiero poner el nombre del username es en otro HTML distinto, una página independiente de esta tal que así:

```
<input class="inp1" type="text" id="usernamew" name="usernamew" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
```

Pero no funciona.

Comment: El HTML distinto, ¿sería el `dashboard.php` al que estás redireccionando?

Comment: el dashboard al que redirecciono es para que se añada a la pagina una vez inicio la sesion, pero es una direccion distinta de donde quiero ponerlo, para una vista general, tengo login.php que es donde realizo el inicio de sesion, luego va a un index que incluye un dashboard y un header con varias opciones, y en addorders.php es donde quiero mostrar el usuario.

Comment: entonces, es una página independiente de esta, que debería mostrar el usuario almacenado en la sesión?

Comment: Si, si es posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El nombre del usuario ya lo estás grabando dentro de una variable de sesión. Si se abre una nueva página, pero se mantiene la misma sesión, sólo se necesita:

1. Inicializar la sesión con [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php).
2. Obtener el valor se la variable [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php).
3. Opcionalmente, como medida de seguridad, usar [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) para escapar caracteres especiales.

```php
<?php

    //Inicializar la sesión
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        //asignar a variable
        $usernameSesion = $_SESSION['username'];
        //asegurar que no tenga "", <, > o &
        $username = htmlspecialchars($usernameSesion);       

        //usarla donde quieras
        echo "<p>¡Hola $username!</p>";
?>

<!-- O dentro del HTML -->
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">


<?php
    } else {
        //No existe username en la sesión
        header('Location: http://url-de-tu-web.com/login.php');
    }
```

Te recomiendo leer acerca del [Manejo de sesiones](http://php.net/manual/es/book.session.php).

---

> **Comentarios sobre tu código:**
>
> Hay un problema importante de seguridad en cómo estás accediendo a la
>   base de datos. Esto es muy importante que lo resuelvas, ya que toda tu
>   base de datos corre peligro. Te recomiendo leer
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)
>
> Por otro lado, si bien `header("Location: dashboard.php");` funciona,
>   es incorrecto. Debería tener la URL completa.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sobre esta misma pregunta, necesito que me muestre mas datos de usuario logueado con el mismo script el cual me trae el username pero recito que también me traiga el nombre, apellido y la fecha de registro en la db usuario, nombres, apellidos, aregistro.